# how to remove multiple character from a column and count the total in column in R

Tags: r

I am programming in R.

I want to remove everything after "/" from a column(date).
The data is :-

```
Date No_of_births
1/1    1482
1/2    1534
1/3    4786
2/3    7846
2/12   1254
2/5    7854
3/1    4587
3/2    6985
3/10   3652
```

I tried this

```
data1$date_1 <-strsplit(data1$date_1,"/")
```

But it give me this data

Sr.No    Date    No_of_births
...`1    c("1", "1")    1482...`
...`2    c("1", "2")    1213...`
...`3    c("1", "3")    1220...`
...`4    c("1", "4")    1319...`
...`5    c("1", "5")    1262...`
...`6    c("1", "6")    1271...`

I dont want  c("1","1") this as an output. I want this as an output:-

```
Date No_of_births  
1    1482   
1    1534  
1    4786  
2    7846  
2    1254  
2    7854  
3    4587  
3    6985  
3    3652
```

Please Help

Comment: `data$Date <- sub("/.*", "", data$Date)` might be what you're looking for

Comment: @PierreLafortune:-- thanks a lot..It worked...but could please explain
What "/.*"  does?

Comment: @PierreLafortune;-- please let me know how can i count the Number of births taken place in on a particular date?

Comment: The code `"/.*"` matches a forward slash and everything after it, and replaces it with `""`, which eliminates it.

Comment: Use `aggregate(No_of_births ~ Date, data, sum)`. For any other questions please create a new question and post.

Comment: @PierreLafortune..thanks